# Replace vertex in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, graphs

I'm completely new to TikZ and took a look at an example graph: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/prims-algorithm/

For a presentation I need to replace a vertex by another vertex at a certain iteration. I tried to do the following:

```
    \foreach \pos/\name \fr in {{(0,1)/1/1}, {(0,1)/2/2}}
        \node<\fr->[vertex] (\name) at \pos {$\name$};
```

This should replace the vertex "1" with vertex "2" on the second iteration. However it does not work since it seems as if the first vertex overwrites the second one. If I change the coordinates of the second vertex it does appear in the second iteration (just not at the right location and vertex "1" is still there. How can I make the first vertex disappear in the second iteration?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `<2->` means on the second and all later slides. `<2>` means on the second slide.

Comment: Also, you are missing a `/` before `\fr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I am allowed to copy code from that link here. However, I made the following changes:

```
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
```

Neither `arrows` nor `shapes` are used. Nor is the `verbatim` package.

Delete the declaration of layers.

Change `\tikzstyle` to `\tikzset`:

```
\tikzset{
  style 1/.style = {settings go here},
  style 2/.style = {settings go here},
  style 3/.style = ...
}
```

Add

```
\foreach \pos / \name / \fr in {{(0,1)/1/1}, {(0,1)/2/2}}
  \node<\fr->[vertex] (\name) at \pos {$\name$};
```

after `\end{pgfonlayer}`.

Change `\begin{pgfonlayer}` to `\begin{scope}[on background layer]`.

Change `\end{pgfonlayer}` to `\end{scope}`.

Most of these changes are just updating the code to the syntax which is now recommended and using the now available library `backgrounds` rather than spinning your own.

I would post an image, but I'm not sure whether that is permissible.